# Create staging environment for react native app

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.multunus.com/blog/2016/06/automated-environment-management-react-native-ios/) post for setting up a staging environment for my react native app. The post asks to add a new configuration calling `Staging` to the Xcode project and use that to build the project. I added the `Staging` config which is a duplicate of the `Release` config but I am not able to build the app using that config. I get following errors:

```
React/RCTBridgeModule.h file not found
```

I don't get this error in `Debug` and `Release` configuration. I read that react-native assigns special meaning to configurations name `Debug` and `Release` but I am not sure how to get around this problem. I also looked at [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) for setting up the staging environment but the initial setup looked a bit complicated to me and something that I didn't understand right away. Whereas the steps listed in the other post are pretty simple to understand which are basically to create a separate config and use the config used to run the app to figure out the environment that the app is running in.

If you have been able to create a staging environment for your react-native app using this approach or some other approach, please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look at this post https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#ios

And my way to do it:

1. Install code-push

First, install the CodePush CLI:

```
npm install -g code-push-cli
```

Then go to root of your React Native project and use command line:

```
npm install --save react-native-code-push
```

Then link the libraries:

```
react-native link react-native-code-push
```

After that, we need to login in code-push with our account (you could find Mobile Center account here):

```
code-push login
```

You also could check if you're already logged in by using command:

```
code-push whoami
```

2. Create Deployment Keys

Before we deploy any updates, we need to register an app with the CodePush service using the following command:

```
code-push app add <appName> <os> <platform>
```

For example:

```
code-push app add myapp-ios ios react-native

code-push app add my-android android react-native
```

After then you should see what you just added in Mobile Center https://mobile.azure.com/apps
And next step is checking the Deployment Key by typing command line:

```
code-push deployment ls <appName> -k
```

For example:

```
code-push deployment ls myapp-ios -k

code-push deployment ls myapp-android -k
```

3. Link Deployment Key

To release an update we need to link Deployment Key to React Native project.
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#ios

4. Release an update

After Deployment Key is finally setting up, the last step is upload the first update.
Change **index.ios.js** and **index.android.js** file into:

```
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";
let codePushOptions = {
checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME,
};

class MyApp extends Component {
...
}

export default MyApp = codePush(codePushOptions)(MyApp);
```

And now type the command line:

```
code-push release-react <appName> <platform>
```

e.g.

```
code-push release-react myapp-ios ios

code-push release-react myapp-android android
```

After this step you will see the first version is uploading to Mobile Center

The rest is now getting very easy. Anytime we want to do an update, we just need to type code-push release-react command line and the code-push will do the silent update.

Push staging to Production also just one command job:

```
code-push promote <APP_NAME> Staging Production -r 100%
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the github issue. That contained all the information I needed to fix the problem.